# Global timer for all users

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How would you go about creating a global timer all users use? Such as a tournament and every 24 hours the timer resets. How would you make all users see the same time and not base it off the client side?

I'd think to use a service like playfab or app42, but how would this work through them anyway?

Thanks

Comment: In your server save *tournament* data, in there just put *time of start* and *username(s)* . It would be nice if you use a data-structure to sort them according to time when inserting. Now check for data which are at the beginning if time or a desired moment to time left or not. If so notify all user on that *tournament* , else rest for `time_to_tournament-notify_time-safe_time`.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code here im gonna tell you the how to but you will need to do research in order to achieve it probably.

You can have a time span in your server, and every time a user logs in you send the time span since the server started to run minus the time that the server has been running, and the client starts running its own timer taking into account that time span.

Im assuming you are working with a client server model here.

Comment: Right, but how would you reset that timer every 24 hours

Comment: Depends, will your clients still be connected to your app? if so, whenever you arrive to the 24 hours timespan you would simply send a new timespan and make your clients adjust to it